# How to get listed in the iOS 8 system wide share menu?

Tags: ios, ios8, info.plist

I'm trying to get my iOS 8 app listed in the iOS 8 system wide share menu for the image extensions .png, .jpg (.jpeg), .gif (static).
What do I need to add to the `info.plist` file? I tried the code below from the [iOS docs example](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Services.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH13-SW1) but that didn't work, my app isn't showing up in the share list.

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
<key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
<dict>
<key>NSExtensionServiceRoleType</key>
<string>NSExtensionServiceRoleTypeEditor</string>
</dict>
<key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
<string>com.apple.ui-services</string>
<key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
<string>ActionViewController</string>
</dict>
```

To make it clear, this is the `iOS 8 Share Menu` (also known as `share sheet`) I mean: http://cdn1.tekrevue.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/ios8-share-sheets-customize.jpg

Comment: Define "didn't work". Keep in mind that the Photos and Mail apps (for some stupid, unknown reason) doesn't offer any chance to open images in 3rd party apps.

Comment: My app isn't showing up in the share menu list. I tried a couple of other apps as well and my app isn't in the list either. Is the string correct to get listed for image files?: `<string>com.apple.ui-services</string>`

Comment: You don't need an extension for this. You want to appear in the "Open in" menu. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application/2781290#2781290

Comment: No, the "Open In" menu is something different. I want my app to get listed in the Share Menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the NSExtensionActivationRule. See Apple's Extension programming guide: [Declaring Supported Data Types for a Share or Action Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW8)

> For example, to declare that your Share extension can support up to
>   ten images, one movie, and one webpage URL, you might use the
>   following dictionary for the value of the NSExtensionAttributes key:
>
> ```
> <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
>     <dict>
>         <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
>         <dict>
>             <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
>             <integer>10</integer>
>             <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsMovieWithMaxCount</key>
>             <integer>1</integer>
>             <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
>             <integer>1</integer>
>         </dict>
>     </dict>
> ```

Comment: Will my app show up in the iOS 8 Share Menu if I add that to my info.plist or do I need to write an extension for it too?

Comment: @Tom, you need to add those attributes to the info.plist of your Share or Action extension.

Comment: That's the confusing part for me. I would like to get my app invoked from the Share Menu and not an extension for the app. Will the code also work if I add it to my apps info.plist?

Comment: What you are referring to as the "Share Menu" is the menu opened by creating a UIActivityViewController. If you want to add something to a UIActivityViewController outside of your app, your only option is to create an extension.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, you need to understand about inter-app communication.
What you need is custom url scheme for your app. Please Refer :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html

Now after you have a custom url sheme, proceed as follows:

To get listed in the system wide share menu,You need to make a custom Activity.

Make a class like the following:
In the YourActivity.h file

```
@interface YourActivity : UIActivity
-(void)someInitialisationMethod:(NSString*)string;
@end
```

and in the YourActivity.m file

```
#import "YourActivity.h"

@implementation YourActivity

- (NSString *)activityType
{
return @"UIActivityCategoryShare";
}

- (NSString *)activityTitle
{ // here give the title of your app or the action name that it performs
return @"YourAppName";
}
+ (UIActivityCategory)activityCategory
{// there are two types of category- share and action
return UIActivityCategoryShare;
}
- (UIImage *)activityImage
{
// Note: These images need to have a transparent background and I recommend these sizes:
// iPadShare@2x should be 126 px, iPadShare should be 53 px, iPhoneShare@2x should be 100
// px, and iPhoneShare should be 50 px. I found these sizes to work for what I was making.

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourActivityImage.png"];
}
else
{
    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourActivityImage.png.png"];
}
}

- (BOOL)canPerformWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems
{
NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
return YES;
}

- (void)prepareWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems
{
NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__);
}

- (UIViewController *)activityViewController
{
NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__);
return nil;
}

- (void)performActivity
{
// This is where you can do anything you want, and is the whole reason for          creating a custom
// UIActivity
NSURL *yourCustomURLMaybe = [NSURL URLWithString:someInitialisedString];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: yourCustomURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: yourCustomURL];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"YourActivity not found");
}
[self activityDidFinish:YES];
}

@end
```

Now that your custom activity is made
You need to fire it up with share menu like this

```
NSString *yourCustomUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YourCustomURLScheme?..."];

NSString *escapeAdded = [yourCustomUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *finalCustomURL = [NSURL URLWithString:escapeAdded];

YourActivity *ca;
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: finalCustomURL])
{
    ca = [[YourActivity alloc]init];
}
else
{
    ca = nil;
}

NSArray *applicationActivityArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:ca,nil];
```

Finally, When you present the share box, add the above array to application Activities:

```
activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[...] applicationActivities:applicationActivityArray];
}
```