# How to register an iOS app for multiple image extensions?

Tags: ios, ios8, info.plist

I would like to register my iOS as an editor for .jpg (.jepg), .png and .gif.
I tried the code below but my app only shows up in the `Open in` iOS menu for the .jpeg extension.
How to make it work for the other two extension?

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>public.jpeg</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.jpeg</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>public.png</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.png</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>GIF image</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.compuserve.gif</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only want one `CFBundleDocumentTypes` section:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>public.jpeg</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.jpeg</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>public.png</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.png</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>GIF image</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.compuserve.gif</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Instead of manually editing Info.plist, enter these details into Xcode. Let it update Info.plist for you. Do this on the Info tab for your target under the "Document Types" section.

Comment: Thank you, finally it works! You commented on my other answer but I don't want to use the "Open In" menu like you suggested - maybe you know an answer for that as well? Bounty added: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28506219/how-to-get-listed-in-the-ios-8-system-wide-share-menu?noredirect=1#comment45332012_28506219

Comment: To make it clear what changed in the original code from the question, I made a diff: https://www.diffchecker.com/PExQ5Dgg

Comment: @rmaddy ca you please tell me this only for public image file name or working for all image?

Comment: Is this still working? It works for me for LSItemContentTypes com.adobe.pdf but I cannot get it working for any type of image (currently testing with iOS 14 and 15).